# Can't retrieve objects from Google Cloud Storage by their mediaLink

Tags: json, acl, google-cloud-storage, bucket

i wrote a project that work well with upload and download objects to/from Google Cloud Storage. I'm able to retrieve the content, the stream, the metadata, but when i get the 'mediaLink' of an object and paste it to the browser, i got this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

the format of mediaLink URL is shown here:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/folder%2Finsidefolder%2Fexample.txt
```

I'm authenticated in my website by the OAuth 2.0 flow, and all the objects uploaded on GCS are with a custom AccessControlList which i decided to set into "allAuthenticatedUsers" in order to give access only to user that are authenticated with my website.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue? Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The media link is not inherently authorized. You need to authorize a download using the media link in the same way you'd authorize any other request: by including an appropriate "Authorization" header.

Without providing read permission to "AllUsers", the media link will not work in a web browser.

Also, "AllAuthenticatedUsers" does not mean users that are authenticated with your website. It means "anybody with any Google account."

Comment: I almost understood your answer, but i don't know how to do it in java or in a html page providing the <a href"...."></a> TAG in order to let the user click on a link and download the file from GCS. Could you help me on that? or i must to re-ask for a new question? Thank you

Comment: Different answers. In Java, if you're using the API client, you can download the media without paying attention to the mediaLink. Here's an example: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java?repo=samples#477

If you want to provide a link to the object in a web browser, you can only use the mediaLink if it's public to AllUsers. Otherwise, you'll need to use a signed URL: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I'll try with that and i'll tell you if something goes wrong. Thank you so much Brandon, you're very kind and clear with explanation.

Comment: I think Signed URL is the solution that best fit my problem, but reading at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signing-Strings  I need an OAuth with Service Account Type Application, and it's not my case, because i'm using Client ID for Web Application. Any idea?

Comment: You can also create a service account explicitly for this purpose. Although may I ask why you want to use AllAuthenticatedUsers instead of just using AllUsers and ignoring auth?

Comment: I'm developing a project for my University, and i would like to allow users(students) connected with my WebSite to upload files on Google Cloud Storage, and keep track of their metadata in a Datastore, in order to populate a Table in a HTML/JSP Page of all files with a direct URL that allow to download them (so i don't want to let anonymous user to download "private" files). Do you think i'm doing wrong? If no, i need to substitute the already existing OAuth with a new one by using Service Account, or just add a new OAuth to the other existent? Thank you so much

Comment: In this context, AllAuthenticatedUsers is no more secure than AllUsers, since literally any Google account, related to your university or no, would have access to these files. If you require more security, you'll need to limit access to be more narrow than  AllAuthenticatedUsers. Otherwise, you may as well set it to AllUsers.

Comment: Ok Brandon, I'll think about it. Thank you very much! I appreciate your help